# Query_more behaviour when the data is modified during execution

Tags: api, batch, query, querylocator

I have a pretty slow operation to apply to a large number of records (1.5M+).

All these records have not be modified for more than six months.

To get these records I use api calls query() then query_more() to apply my logic by batch. The whole process will probably take a few days.

If, during the execution, the record n°120000 is modified, will it be retrieved with query more or will it be filtered out ?

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_querymore.htm) say a new QueryLocator is generated but I don't understand what that means.

> The queryMore() call processes subsequent records in up to 500-record
> chunks, resets the server-side cursor, and returns a newly generated
> QueryLocator.

Answer (score 1):

I did not have to go through a similar scenario but I think you have your answer in the following part of the documentation.

> We recommend the following:
>
> - When possible, avoid paging by filtering your queries of external objects to return fewer rows than the batch size, which by default is
>   500 rows. Remember, obtaining each batch requires a queryMore() call,
>   which results in a Web service callout.
> - If the external data frequently changes, avoid using queryMore() calls. If the external data is modified between queryMore() calls, you
>   can get an unexpected QueryResult.

If this is applicable to external object records, it should also be applicable to internal object records as well.

I hope it helps.